# Rectifying diode for boost converter in nixie clock

Tags: boost, nixie

I've been working on [this schematic](http://www.nixieuhren.de/downloads/108b-6.pdf) to create a nixie clock. But I don't understand the need for **recifying** diode [D5](https://www.bucek.name/pdf/byv95.pdf) in the schematic. Wouldn't a standard diode work? Does it have to do with the "back emf" produced by the inductor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D5 is part of a high frequency boost circuit formed around the MOSFET Q7 and the inductor L1. together they dump energy into capacitor C4 and they will use high switching frequencies possibly circa 100 kHz. Generic boost converter: -

[image]

Your boost converter featuring D5: -

[image]

This means that you must use a fast diode or the extended reverse recovery time will significantly reduce your high voltage rail and/or efficiency. Reverse recovery time means that when a diode goes from forward to reverse bias, current will flow against the grain for a short period of time and for a 1N4007 (for instance) this can be as long as 30 us. 30 us would severely disrupt the working of your boost regulator.

Fast diodes are in the low tens of nano seconds with a diode like the BAS16 being about 5 ns (for example). Nixie tubes are cool BTW!

Comment: Nixie tubes of any decent size are EXPENSIVE, too. Would be nice to see the new LED filaments (having 28 LEDs in a string requiring about 70 V to run them at 10mA) being incorporated in some new NIXIE replacement devices. Or some new manufacturer coming into the NIXIE marketplace due to the prices now being high enough to make some money at it.

Comment: @jonk: as soon as new ones are made they will no longer be cool.

Comment: @dandavis Well, I have ZERO coolness genes. I *DO* however enjoy being able to read a clock at night from a distance and would very much appreciate building a nixie clock. But I have NO interest at all in having something that is there because it is *expensive* and it shows off that I have more money than they do. (I am in the top 1% of the US, but I also spend 400 hours every year volunteering to help others less fortunate and donate significant funds to help those groups, as well. So I enjoy nifty ideas that others can *afford* themselves. Nixies are not affordable by the hoi polloi.)

Comment: @jonk Have you considered one of those jumbo LED clocks?  You can see them from across the room and they're a lot cheaper than a custom Nixie one.

Comment: @PaulUszak I have a couple of analog clocks with the bright hands that turn on when it is dark. Very efficient and they work fine. But I like Nixies too. And so do others. It just would be nice to have a new manufacturer making them and getting the prices back down so that regular folks could enjoy them without sacrificing rent money.

Comment: I remember as a kid having a wristwatch that had luminous hands that you could see in the dark but I was told it was a cancer risk so I took up smoking instead. Irrelevant of course!

Comment: Thank you for the info! But is there a reason why its a rectifying diode? What part of that circuit requires a rectifier?

Comment: @TranslucentDragon which part of the answer to your previous question about the boost converter didn't you understand (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/303304/nixie-clock-power-supply)? I have added a picture of a generic boost converter and a snippet of your circuit to my answer. Maybe you are referring to another D5 that I cannot see? Maybe you are confusing the terms rectifier and diode - they are the same thing.

Comment: @andy aka I think I have a misunderstanding of the term rectifier! I assumed it was a specific type of diode that also acted as a rectifier circuit. Other than the name, are there any differences at all between a rectifier and a diode?

Comment: I thought so, no, the two are the same.

Comment: If you are content with this answer please consider formally accepting it. I see that you haven't done this on questions you've raised before so I suppose, you weren't aware of this process.

Comment: Sorry, relatively new to the forum process but I think I'm getting it. If I have a related question, is it typical to ask in comments or create a new post?

Comment: If the guy leaving the answer thinks you might be making new questions too far away from the original he/she should make noises and advise.

Comment: @Andyaka I was looking at a few more posts about boost converters and see you've written in a lot of them. Do you mind if I ask you some questions directly? Is there a PM system for this forum?

Comment: There is no PM system and I joined this site to answer questions formally raised because then I control the time I spend on answers rather than get pestered LOL!